# Replacing the last occurence of a character in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line

```
if (($x > 0) && ($flag == 1))
```

I want to replace the last ")" with a colon (:). so it becomes

```
if (($x > 0) && ($flag == 1):
```

I tried using  `$line =~ s/\)$/\:/;` but it wouldnt work

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is it the only line in the string? I'm a bit confused because that should have worked if so.

Answer (score 2):

The following should replace the last `)` with a `:`:

```
$line =~ s/\)([^)]*)$/:$1/;
```

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx you're looking for is

```
$line =~ s/.*\K\)/:/;
```

If you're using *strict* and *warnings*, you'll probably run into issues with using variables in $line if they haven't been declared earlier. You should read up on [Perl Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: @krisku If you view the page I linked from perldoc.perl.org, \K is under Extended Patterns "..which causes the regex engine to keep everything it had matched prior to the \K and not include it in $&".

Have you tried running the regex yourself? 
`my $var = "if (($x > 0) && ($flag == 1))";
print "$var \n";
$var =~ s/.*\K\)/:/;
print $var;`

Comment: @Kenosis Thanks for that, it's been a long day :/

Comment: @JamesPowell - You did good using `\K`; my suggestion is only a minor variation of your work.

Comment: @JamesPowell Sorry, but my perl v 5.8.8 do not support \K. I guess I feel a bit old now..

Comment: @Kenosis After realizing that newer perl-versions support \K and what it does, *your* regex makes no sense. Why start a pattern match with a directive to keep anything matched before if? That is a no-op.

Comment: @Kenosis But what would be the use of `\K` in `s/\K\)$/:/`? Wouldn't it just be simpler with `s/\)$/:/`? (which by the way failed for OP).

Comment: @Jerry - You're quite right.  I don't understand its failure with the OP using it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be whitespace (such as the newline) at the end of the line (unless you have explicitly removed it), so the following regexp should do the trick (while preserving the newline):

```
$line =~ s/\)(\s*)$/:$1/;
```